# Sharepoint 2016 - Update

Tags: updates, sharepoint

I got a quite basic question about installing Sharepoint Updates.

*Background:* 
We run SP2016 on premise behind our company firewall + proxy. We can't use Windows Update for patching. We did not install any patches/fixes.

I want to install at least every update from 2016 until December 2018. Do I need to install every single Update from Microsoft Page, or may i install something like an update package?

Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 0):

For the latest cumulative update for SharePoint 2016, see the Microsoft Technet article
[December 2018 CU for SharePoint Server 2016 is available for download](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2018/12/11/december-2018-cu-for-sharepoint-server-2016-is-available-for-download/).

Follow the instructions in the article for downloading and installing the listed
updates.

Microsoft does not offer any recent offline installation ISO file for
SharePoint 2016 that contains all the updates, but it does offer the newer
SharePoint Server 2019 download dating from 23-10-2018, if your subscription
includes it.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link to follow all the updates. 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/sharepoint-updates

Make sure every server in the farm has the same update version or some features stop working. Also use the Sharepoint Configuration Wizard after the update. Sharepoint will 'repair' or align all the changes. After the wizard, everyone reports healthy again.